# Click function do not working after jquery validation added

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
$(document).on('click', '#dodaj', function(e) {
  $("#addscrap").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      job: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
      },
      keywords: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    messages: {
      job: {
        required: "Podaj nazwę analizy do wykonania",
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("brakuje {0} znaków!")
      },
      keywords: {
        required: "Podaj słowa kluczowe do analizy",
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("brakuje {0} znaków!")
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var data = $("#addscrap").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "views/addscrap.php",
        beforeSend: function(data) {
          document.getElementById('alert').style.display = '';
          $("#alert").text("dodawanie zadania...");
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data['error'] == 'exist') {
            document.getElementById('alerterror').style.display = '';
            $('#alerterror').text('Zadanie już istnieje');
            document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none';
          } else if (data['error'] == 'add') {
            document.getElementById('alerterror').style.display = 'none';
            $('#alert').text('Dodano zadanie');
            document.getElementById('alert').style.display = '';
            getlist();
          }
        },
        error: function(data) {
          document.getElementById('alerterror').style.display = '';
          $("#alerterror").text("Błąd, spróbuj ponownie");
          document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

After when i added a jquery validation to this JS, I cannot click button #dodaj, there is of course no errors in console. Can someone please help me to resolve this ? Need to add a document on load function ?

This works only if i remove submitHandler section, but the ajax only run without doing validation on form.

```
           <script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

                $("#addscrap").validate({ 
                      rules: {
                        job: {
                          required: true,
                          minlength: 3
                        },
                        keywords: {
                          required: true,
                          minlength: 5
                        }
                      },
                      messages: {
                        job: {
                          required: "Podaj nazwę analizy do wykonania",
                          minlength: jQuery.validator.format("brakuje {0} znaków!")
                        },
                         keywords: {
                          required: "Podaj słowa kluczowe do analizy",
                          minlength: jQuery.validator.format("brakuje {0} znaków!")
                        }
                      },
                                                                submitHandler: function(form) {
                                           var data = $("#addscrap").serialize();
                                            $.ajax({
                                                data: data,
                                                type: "post",
                                                dataType: "JSON",
                                                url: "views/addscrap.php",
                                                beforeSend: function(data) {
                                                        document.getElementById('alert').style.display = '';
                                                    $("#alert").text("dodawanie zadania...");

                                                },
                                                success: function(data){
                                                if(data['error'] == 'exist') {
                                                    document.getElementById('alerterror').style.display = '';
                                                         $('#alerterror').text('Zadanie już istnieje');
                                                     document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none';
                                                }
                                                else if(data['error'] == 'add') {
                                                    document.getElementById('alerterror').style.display = 'none';
                                                         $('#alert').text('Dodano zadanie');
                                                     document.getElementById('alert').style.display = '';
                                                     getlist();
                                                }
                                                },
                                                error: function(data) {
                                                    document.getElementById('alerterror').style.display = '';
                                                    $("#alerterror").text("Błąd, spróbuj ponownie");
                                                    document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none';
                                                }
                                            });
                                          }

                       });


});


</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered enabling validation on document ready? assigning a validation on every click handling seems not a good choice.

Comment: You're only creating the `validate` instance when you click the `#dodaj` button - there is no other action performed. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: this button $dodaj turn a form where need to validate inputs. if valid run ajax

Comment: any idea what is wrong ? #dodaj button make no action, no validation no ajax,

Comment: ok i update my question, now is ok, but problem is that i cant handle a click button, how to do this ?